# Share image using intent chooser

Tags: android, android-intent, android-facebook

How can I share images using intent chooser. I have tried

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/png");

        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
          Uri.parse(url));
```

where url is from internet

I am able to share text using the above code the image doesnt get attached.

Answer (score -1):

try doing this instead i think it will work

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(filename));
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

Comment: so do you mean that i am supposed to save in sd card before posting?